# Call method2 till method1 is 'sleeping'

Tags: c#, timer

I want to call method1 then put it into 'sleep' and while method1 is sleeping call method2 till method1 'wake up'. I read some about [System.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) but I have no idea how to call method2 while method1 is wating and so on.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();

            p.method1();

            p.method2();
        }
        public void method1()
        {
            //Do smth and wait X seconds
        }
        public void method2()
        {
            //Do smth while method1 is waiting
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "call method2 till method1 'wake up'"? Repeatedly call it? Or somehow abort `method2` when `method1` wakes up? And what does "wake up" mean?

Comment: I think this might be an X-Y problem. You want to solve X and you think by doing Y you'll solve X, but you don't know how to do Y, so you're asking. Maybe you need to ask us about X instead?

Comment: I've got two methods in infinity loop. I want  first one to make something and wait for example 20 seconds and when method1 is waitng those 20 secounds the secound method will be doing somthing else for amount of time that first method is waiting. 
Method1 - do something and wait
Method2 - do something while method1 is wating
And again, and again.

Comment: Then there's no need for a timer. `method1` simply calls `method2` which then keeps an eye on the time that has passed while it is processing and once 20 seconds has expired then it returns control to `method1`. No timers. No multi-threaing.